# How do I get sidebar to be rendered on left when viewing object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, sidebar

I'm pretty new to rails so sorry if this I'm not clear. I have an object called projects in layouts I have _left_column.html.erb that adds stuff to the left column based on what page I'm on. In this case the stuff is info of other objects that are associated with it (things like tasks).

Screenshot:

[image]

I works as shown but only for the project with id of 1. I'm not sure how to get this to work on all projects. Thanks!

Comment: You're hard-coding the id of 1 in your view. If you want it to be something other than 1, you have to get the id dynamically.

Comment: just some tip for you, when you asking in SO, please do not put code with an image, you can upload here just copy / paste your code and format the code with code toolbar, the reason for this: if so community want to answer your question they don't have to type all your code again

Comment: Sorry for posting an image instead of a code. And I know that I hardcoded in the value of 1 and need to get the id dynamically but not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give some tips for your code

```
<% case request.path.split('?').first.to_s %>
  <% when 'projects/1' %>
    # this is the problem, 
    # all code below when 'projects/1' only running if projects equal to 1
    # if you want all code below running you can try remove the logic when
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```